# How to make the navigational bar full width and bring tabs to middle?

Tags: html, css, web, menu

My website is this www.bangkokvisitors.com I'm new to css and HTML. I used a child theme and edited the style.css. But the output doesn't look like the way I want.

I added these to css

```
.menu{
height: 42px;
}

.menu li{
position:relative;
float:left;
left:33%;
margin-top:0px;
}
```

this seems work for me. But the margin doesn't change after i save the code and reload the webpage. Help me with this please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your header tag after body tag. You also need to change some class in it.

```
<header multilinks-noscroll="true" id="header" class="blog-header">
    <div multilinks-noscroll="true" class="blog-title container"><a multilinks-noscroll="true" href="http://bangkokvisitors.com/" title="bangkokvisitors.com" rel="home">bangkokvisitors.com</a></div>
    <div multilinks-noscroll="true" class="blog-description container">To shop, to hangout and to explore the city of Angels | <a multilinks-noscroll="true" href="http://bangkokvisitors.com/feed/" title="Subscribe to the RSS Feed of this site" id="rss">RSS</a></div>
    <nav multilinks-noscroll="true" id="blog-menu" class="menu">

        <!--YOUR MENU CODE GOES HERE-->

    </nav>
</header>
```